# Joining Term-Document-Matrix with a matix or a list

Tags: r, matrix

I generated a Term-Document-Matrix, now I want to select terms in the Term-Document-Matrix according to a list of words. So I'm planning to combine the Term-Document-Matrix with the list and remove the incomplete rows.

I only find methods to combine two Term-Document-Matrix but not combining Term-Document-Matrix with a list or matrix. How to do this?

this is the list negemo

```
             V1
             1 unpleasant
             2      grief
             3       sobs
             4    sobbing
             5     raging
             6      mourn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of words as a vector you can use the dictionary command when creating the document term matrix.

See example:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeNumbers)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("smart"))
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stemDocument)

# List of words
low <- c("price", "oil", "barrel", "contract")

# restict dtm to list of words
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control=list(dictionary = lib))

head(inspect(dtm))

     Terms
Docs  barrel contract oil price
  127      2        2   5     5
  144      0        0  12     6
  191      1        1   2     2
  194      1        1   1     2
  211      0        0   1     0
  236      4        0   7     8
```